# Cloned git repo, can't revert changes?

Tags: git

Playing with git I have successfully cloned repository and started making changes. Now what's bugging me is that with `git status` I get `nothing to commit (working directory clean)` . How is that possible if all files are already in repository ? Should I manually add files to index ? Also, I'm not sure how to revert changes, entering `git checkout master` nothing changes and I wanted original files ?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't staged the changes to the files you have changed/added after you cloned the repository. You have to do this using the `git add` command. If you try `git status` there's likely files that you have changed that are not staged for the next commit. Try `git add your_filename_here` and see if your changes come up when you try `git status`. If they do then you can do `git commit` to save those changes.

Comment: I suggest to start with a basic tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You get `nothing to commit (working directory clean)` because no change have been made (by you) on the working copy. Only when you modify and add files will you get a status notifying you of such changes.

To revert local modifications to files, you can try `git reset --hard`